# Regex for first_name validation to allow only letters and white space AFTER a letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I'm validating a User's first_name in my User model and i'd like to allow users to only input alphabetical letters as well as one whitespace after a letter.

I'm able to validate letters using:

```
validates_format_of :first_name, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+\z/
```

How do I validate the inclusion of one white space only after a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
/\A[a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?\z/
```

`(?: [a-zA-Z]+)?` makes 2nd part i.e. single space and letters after it optional.

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/sn3qwfaRTO)